# Quartz jobs not running

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Working with Java Quartz, I was able to schedule one job. Then I tried something like the following code to be able to add an other job. Now neither seems to trigger at the defined time. What am I doing wrong?

I want to use approach like following, not xml configuration.

```
   scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();


   JobDetail jobFull = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", IntegrationJobFull.class);
   JobDetail jobPartial = new JobDetail("job2", "group1", IntegrationJobPartial.class);

   CronTrigger triggerFull = new CronTrigger("trigger1", "group1", "job1", "group1", "0 15 3 * * ?");
   CronTrigger triggerPartial = new CronTrigger("trigger2", "group1", "job2", "group1", "* 0,30 * * * ?");

   scheduler.addJob(jobFull, false);
   scheduler.addJob(jobPartial, false);

   scheduler.scheduleJob(triggerFull);
   scheduler.scheduleJob(triggerPartial);

   scheduler.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `JobDetail`s created above are non-durable, this means that the `addJob` method will fail.    Use the overloaded `scheduleJob` method to associate the job and the trigger.

Remove the `addJob` and `scheduleJob` calls and replace with:

```
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobFull, triggerFull);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobPartial, triggerPartial);
```

Also `*` has been specifed the seconds field for trigger2.  This will mean that the job will be triggered every second for the specified minutes.  I'm not sure if that was the intention.

The desired cron expression may be:

```
"0 0,30 * * * ?"
```